# Why do some men wear the kitul under their suit jacket at their wedding?

Tags: minhag, clothing, wedding, men-male, kittel

I'm not sure if there is any halachic basis for any of this, but I've seen at most weddings the *chasan* just wears the *kitul* over the suit jacket. At a few weddings though, particularly in Israel, many *chasanim* wear the *kitul* underneath their jacket. Any reason for this?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=116

Comment: According to R' Binyamin Shlomo Hamburger, Germans don't wear a sargenes (kittel) until a year after their wedding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend of mine was told by his rebbe at Chofetz Chaim yeshiva in Queens that it's a *personal* Yom Kippur -- hence, wear the kittel, but not out in the open.

Answer (score 4):

The Lev Ita and Yismach Lev brings down the one should wear something ontop of kittel.

see it here http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol4Issue12.pdf

Comment: Why do they recommend this?